# ImportError: cannot import name root_dir

Tags: python

Im trying to run my Python app but I am getting the following error message:

```
File "services/user.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-12-01 15:28:34 -0800 [web][cinema-app-web-3-6774f77795-k5mqz]: from services import root_dir, nice_json
2020-12-01 15:28:34 -0800 [web][cinema-app-web-3-6774f77795-k5mqz]: ImportError: cannot import name root_dir
```

This is the folder structure I have today:

```
cinema-app
  setup.py
  requirements.txt
  database
     bookings.json
     movies.json
     showtimes.json
     users.json
  services
     __init__.py
     bookings.py
     movies.py
     showtimes.py
     user.py
```

I then run the app by using:

```
python services/user.py
```

but then I get the error message above.

Here is the content of my __init__.py:

```
import os
import json
from flask import make_response

def root_dir():
    """ Returns root director for this project """
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__ + '/..'))


def nice_json(arg):
    response = make_response(json.dumps(arg, sort_keys = True, indent=4))
    response.headers['Content-type'] = "application/json"
    return response
```

Here is the user.py file content:

```
from services import root_dir, nice_json
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound, ServiceUnavailable
import json
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)

with open("{}/database/users.json".format(root_dir()), "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return nice_json({
        "uri": "/",
        "subresource_uris": {
            "users": "/users",
            "user": "/users/<username>",
            "bookings": "/users/<username>/bookings",
            "suggested": "/users/<username>/suggested"
        }
    })

@app.route("/users/<username>/suggested", methods=['GET'])
def user_suggested(username):
    """
    Returns movie suggestions. The algorithm returns a list of 3 top ranked
    movies that the user has not yet booked.
    :param username:
    :return: Suggested movies
    """
    raise NotImplementedError()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You appear to have created `__inity__.py` rather than `__init__.py`.

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace that goes with that error?  I don't see anywhere that you're trying to import `root_dir` nor anywhere you're trying to use it.

Comment: If you're getting the error trying to run `python services/user.py`, then it sure would help to show us that python file...

Comment: ...and the file where the error is actually occuring, if that's not it.

Comment: Just added the content of the user.py file above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a package, your code is right. To simplify, I rewrite the `__init__.py` and `user.py`:

user.py:

```
from services import root_dir, nice_json

def main():
    print(root_dir)
    print(nice_json)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

__init__.py:

```
def root_dir():
    pass

def nice_json():
    pass
```

And you can run in terminal this way:

```
user@computer$ python -m services/user
<function root_dir at 0x7fd1d0083670>
<function nice_json at 0x7fd1d0083700>
```

Here dont use the 'py' extension, the '-m' options tells python this is a modular import. You can still import your package from python:

```
user@computer$ python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Aug  4 2020, 11:16:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from services import user
>>> user.main()
<function root_dir at 0x7fa2e21a2dd0>
<function nice_json at 0x7fa2e21b01d0>
```

Code this way you can use your package when it is in PATH or in site-packages python dir.

Comment: I tried using that but now I get this: `File "/var/lib/pyenv/versions/2.7.16/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
[worker3]: "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
[worker3]: File "/var/lib/pyenv/versions/2.7.16/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
[worker3]: exec code in run_globals
[worker3]: File "/home/application/current/services/bookings.py", line 12, in <module>
[worker3]: with open("{}/database/bookings.json".format(root_dir()), "r") as f:
[worker3]: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'None/database/bookings.json'`

Comment: How are you using your module? If you run using `runpy` module (or using a module that uses `runpy`), the runpy overwrite the `__file__` attribute. In this case, your function `root_dir` will not return what you want. With this traceback, your code is running over runpy.

Comment: Thats right, its running over `runpy`. Any ideas of what to do in this case?

Comment: Please tell how exactly this script run. Is a PYENV (conda, virtualenv)? Which OS (debian, ubuntu, openSuse). How do you call it?

Comment: But you can try `os.getcwd()` or `inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())`.